# Instance variable getting set to null if activity is recreated by OS

Tags: android, android-activity

I have been struggling with this problem for quite some time now.

Instance variables of my main activity are getting set to null if I start app after a day. So, for my users every other day app crashes once and then restarts just fine. I am assuming that the activity gets killed and recreated and when they start app the next day.

Basically, what may be happening is due to "onsavedinstance" the views are getting recreated, but the data that those views need is not yet available as I do not store the data in the bundle.

How can I prevent it? I am not inclined towards storing each and every variable in bundle as it's a bad design. What's the best way to do it?

Here is my code:

Basically i am trying to populate my bootstrap data (dataWrapper) from server on "onCreate". I use this data object in subsequent code. All works fine on first app launch. But when user opens app after a day or 7-8 hours, the object "dataWrapper" turns out to be null.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //other initialization code
        getData();
        //remaining code
    }

    protected DataWrapper dataWrapper;

    private void getData(){
    try {
        //url for fetching data 
        String url = "http://....."
        new FetchAndPopulateMarketDataAsyncTask(this){
            @Override public void onPostExecute(DataWrapper result)
            {
                if(result==null){
                    //server or no internet error 
                }
                else{
                    dataWrapper = (DataWrapper)result;
                }
            }
        }.execute(new URL(url));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Rony

Comment: Please post the code of your Activity

Comment: Save your app-state into a persisted storage (SharedPreferences or sqlite e.g.) and load it in your onResume() method of the main activity. Without seeing your code it's difficult to say more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Android will kill or release memory of background applications as needed. So, you need to maintain state of your application when it goes into the background.

Try overriding both onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to save and restore the values of these instance variables.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.. But what's a good way to store instance variables? I have so many such variables and it would be ready bad and error prone to store and restore  each of them separately.